# When is a convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ finitely generated by a subset?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-cone

A convex cone is a set $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ closed under adittion and positive scalar multiplication. If $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ we consider $p(S)$ defined as the set of all positive linear combinations (this is, all linear combinations where the coefficients are positive). Of course $p(S)$ is a convex cone.

> If $C$ is a convex cone, is there $S\subseteq C$ finite such that $C=p(S)$?

The answer to this question is no. For instance, take $S$ as any two independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and take $p(S)$ without its boundary. The obtained convex cone is not finitely generated.

It's simpler than that. It can be proved that $p(S)$ is always closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ finite. Then how about this?

> If $C$ is a closed convex cone, is there $S\subseteq C$ finite such that $C=p(S)$?

Does anyone know a counterexample or is it true?

Comment: Consider the cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by $\{x | x_1 = 1, x_2^2+x_3^2 =1 \}$.

Comment: A good reference is Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis".

Comment: Or the ice cream cone ... or the epigraph of $\|x\|^2$ ... or come of positive semidefinite matrices and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample in $\Bbb R^3$: the full cone with basis a disk (cone, for the layman). A finitely generated convex cone in $\Bbb R^3$ would just be some sort of full infinite pyramid with convex polygonal basis.

**Addition:** I've been tipped by the person next to me that it is however true for [*polyhedral cones*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone), id est, cones in the form $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\,Ax\ge 0\}$ for some matrix $A$. Truth to be told, I cannot weight on this, though.

Comment: That person is right...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the **Addition** part of G.Sassatelli

The claim is true for polyhedral cones.

Proof: (Sketch)

Let $C:=\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\,Ax\ge 0\}$, and $B \subset R^n$ be the closed Unit ball w.r.t $\|\|_{\infty}$ norm, i.e., $B$ is Unite Square centered origin. Now  $C \cap B$ is compact polyhedral which generates $C$, in another words , $C=P (C \cap B)$. Note that for generating $C$ we don't need whole set $C \cap B$, but its extreme points are enough! Since $C \cap B$ is compact polyhedral it has  finite extreme points, Therefore   $C = P(ext(C \cap B))$.